# Lambda Invoke not triggering second lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, invoke

I have gone through similar threads to fix this issue but I have had no luck. Both lambdas can be trigger independently of one another, and I am able to invoke the second Lambda through the command line, but my code does not work.

```
'use strict'
/* eslint max-statements: ['error', 100, { 'ignoreTopLevelFunctions': true }] */
const RespHelper = require('../../lib/response')
const { uuid } = require('uuidv4')
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const DB = require('./dynamo')
const respHelper = new RespHelper()
const Dynamo = new DB()
const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
  region: 'us-west-2'
})

const secondLambda = async (lambdaData) => {
  var params = {
    LogType: 'Tail',
    FunctionName: 'second_lambda_name',
    InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
    Payload: JSON.stringify(lambdaData)
  }
  lambda.invoke(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      console.log(`Success: ${data.Payload}`)
    }
  })
}

exports.handler = async event => {
  const id = uuid()
  let bodyData = {
    uuid: id,
    user: 'owner@email.com',
    processingStatus: 'IN_PROGRESS'
  }
  let payloadData = {
    uuid: id,
    user: 'owner@email.com',
    processingStatus: 'COMPLETE'
  }
  try {
    await Dynamo.writeRecordToDB(bodyData)
    await secondLambda(payloadData)
    return respHelper.sendResponse(200, { message: bodyData })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Failure: ${err}`)
    return respHelper.sendResponse(400, { message: 'ERROR' })
  }
}
```

I have double checked the lambda role and it has the Invoke Lambda and Invoke Asynchronous Invoke permission on all resources. Console outputs don't give me any indication of why this is not working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the `secondLambda` have `async` keyword but it doesn't need. If you want to `await` the second lambda in the `handler` function, you can `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => ...` in the `secondLambda` an then in the `lambda.invoke` callback call the `resolve` with the data when success  or `reject` in case of error.

Comment: Hi @sean-hill, you have a mix of async and callback in the `secondLambda`, try using the `.promise()` method and remove the callback. I made the changes in this gist ( https://gist.github.com/pepoviola/311ed41c425a3da39dc80237f263b969 ).

Answer (score 0):

You're awaiting a `callback` when you need to await a `promise`

```
const secondLambda = async lambdaData =>
    lambda
        .invoke({
            LogType: 'Tail',
            FunctionName: 'second_lambda_name',
            InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
            Payload: JSON.stringify(lambdaData),
        })
        .promise()
```